# Given N and e in RSA and the ability to get signature s for any message m, can you find the value of the private key d?

Tags: rsa, signature

Given N and e in RSA and the ability to get signature s for any message m ($s=m^d \mod{n}$), can you find the value of the private key d?

Comment: Did you search on our site? Are you asking for a TextBook signature that is already insecure? Or are you asking for RSA-PSS? Note that signature requires hashing of the message since the first true Rabin Signature Scheme,

Comment: @kelalaka on the site I found this https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/how-does-rsa-signature-verification-work that shows how to find a signature m without d and I also found how to find N without having it initially, but I haven't found how to work out d given N and e and the ability to find the signature for any message m. The signature I'm talking about is $s=m^d\mod{n}$ and you can modify m to any value you like and receive the value of $s$

Comment: Nope, signature requires the private key.

Comment: You're right I mad an error again :) I think I'm tired

Comment: **Hint:** If you can find, then [you can solve factorisation problem, too](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89883/18298)

Comment: so basically then there is no known method to get d right @kelalaka

Comment: Does [this answer about chosen-plaintext and -ciphertext attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2331/8287), or [this question about textbook chosen-plaintext attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18631/8287) cover your use-case?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude those are about encryption, the question is about the signature.

Comment: @kelalaka I thought [those are the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454069/1874170)? "signing" a message \[digest\] is just encrypting it with the "wrong half" of the key

Comment: $e$ is known so you can play the CPA, CCA games. $d$ is secret. They are not, both require different security requirements and padding to achieve that. Read the latest answer to the link you gave. The main objective in the signature is forging.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Please have a look at [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15997/is-rsa-encryption-with-a-private-key-the-same-as-signature-generation). Although in fairness, the question is about textbook RSA without any padding or conversions; my Q/A is not much about textbook RSA. But please, do not confuse signature generation as "encryption with the private key", there is really no such thing.